# Can someone tell me, which font is this in vs code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, fonts

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AIBHH.png)

I hope someone can remenber it, I forgot it's name.

Comment: look in your `settings.json`

Answer (score 0):

If the font you shared with us was applied in your vscode, would you try these methods?

1. Open `Settings` through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd> or `File > Preferences > Settings`
2. Search `Font-Family` on 'search settings'
3. then you may see `Editor: Font-Family` box,
4. You can check the font applied in your vscode.

Comment: I want this font back, by mistake I removed it, that's why I need the name of the font!